# Highchart series is choping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I want to create chart for 24 hrs data using highcharts , but Its seems first two data is not rendering properly, its rendering  11 column in place of 12,
Can someone help me.. I have create example here

Comment: can you show a demo using jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1u2Lzq34/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from your code

```
  min: Date.UTC(year,month,perviousDay),
  max: Date.UTC(year,month,todayDate),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your series data the first timestamp refers to the date **22nd January** and as per your `min` parameter **Date.UTC(year,month,perviousDay)** which is referring the date of  **23rd January** so your graph is ommiting the first record of 22nd January because of the minimum value of the axis and same will apply with `max` parameter. 
So either you can remove `min` and `max` parameters or based on your series data you can set `min` and `max` in such a way that it doesn't omit any data. Hope this helps.